# Getting a PHP error

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-error-1064

**connection.php:**

```
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","networka_root","secret");
if (!$con) die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error()); 

mysql_select_db("networka_simple_login", $con);

$sql="INSERT INTO `networka` (`username`, `password`,)
             VALUES ('$_POST[username]','$_POST[password]')";

if (!mysql_query($sql, $con)) die('Error: ' . mysql_error()); 
echo "1 record added";

mysql_close($con)
```

The error I get when I put in my `username` and `password`:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near `) VALUES ('username','password')` at line 1

Comment: If you didn't already saw it you can take a tour here: http://stackoverflow.com/tour and see how the site works! (Welcome on SO!)

Answer (score 7):

You have an unnecessary comma after your column identifier list:

```
(username, password,) 
                 ^^^^
                 HERE
```

Remove it.

[Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [red box](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers). **You are also wide open to [SQL injections](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174)**

Comment: @Fred-ii- That was definitely not easy to spot with the originally formatting of the question.

Comment: @JohnConde I think here is one for you: http://stackoverflow.com/q/28228109/3933332 :D i think you are familiar with this formatting.

Comment: [For anyone wondering what I was talking about...](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/28228052/1) - *the brick wall.*

Comment: @Rizier123 That pushed me over the edge. I am now legally blind.

Comment: @JohnConde you didn't know?! well yeahhhh! he right there